# Unable to install Opencart 3.0.2.0 in Linux Server

Tags: php, opencart-3

When I try to install `Opencart V3.0.2.0` in Linux server, getting following error message.

> Fatal error: Internal Zend error - Missing class information for in
>   /system/storage/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ParserInterface.php on line
>   31

I am not able to start my installation process. Any idea, Please help.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not guaranteed to work, but since few people reported that they have been able to solve it disabling APC I would give it a try.

If you want to disable Alternative PHP Cache (APC), you can do so by modifying your PHP initialization file file.

1. Using your hosting account's editor (Web & Classic / cPanel / Plesk), open your website's PHP initialization file.

   Note: I recommend backing up your PHP initialization file file before modifying it. You can do this by copying and renaming it in your file manager.
2. On a new line, type `apc.enabled=0`
3. Save your changes.